# To enable crawling urls with special characters in nutch

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using apache nutch-1.5.1 version and solr 3.6.2 integrated with hadoop 1.0.3.
I  I want to crawl domain for example "www.my-website.com" there are different pages like
 1. www.my-website.com/page.1
 2. www.my-website.com/page.2..
www.my-website.com/page.1 there is lot of information like(www.my-website.com/page.1/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=222) i am unable to crawl this type of links (which contains the special chracters(?,=))..
I commented in regex.urlfilter.txt

> ## skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
>
> ## -[?*!@=]..

.
but still there is no difference in the output ....Please share your thoughts
Thanks in advance
Jaipal R

Comment: Are you deleting your crawl folder so that nutch does a full recrawl?
Also, can you post your config files?

Comment: Thanks for your replay... i am crawling freshly and moreover i running this nutch on hadoop ..

Comment: can you post the automaton-urlfilter.txt, crawl-urlfilter.txt, nutch-site.conf, regex-urlfilter.txt files?

Comment: I am using those are default only.Only thing i changed is nutch-site.xml and regex-urlfilter.txt(which is asper Nutch wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at crawl-urlfilter.txt.
There's a similar entry and it should also be commented if you *really* want to crawl these urls.

```
# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-[?*!@=]
```

Be careful or you might end in an infinite loop situation, e.g paging that never ends.

You should add an exception instead of changing the rule.

```
   +www.my-website.com/page.*
   # skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc. 
   -[?*!@=]
```